# STRUCK AT BOOT ANIMATION AFTER CHANGING IT MANUALLY

Tags: boot-loop

Guys i need urjent help as i my device got stuck in the boot animation after i chenged it manually. my device (BSNL PENTA WS704DX) is rooted. Now even after wiping data or formatting data an hard resetting i again find the same boot animation and the stucked mobile.. guyus please help me out.... how can  i remove that boot animation as i dont have any custom recovery installed in my device. :) waiting fr your answers.. :) :)

Comment: You may want to ensure that the boot animation file at **/system/media** is called **boot.zip**, and is owned by **root** (user **0**, group **0**), with **rw-r--r--** (**644**) permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Use ADB (Android Debug Bridge)

search for and install universal adb driver 
or your devices adb driver !

Once installed,

Wait for the bootloop and run this command in adb via command terminal (cmd)

```
adb devices
```

Does your device show up on pc ?
if it does show up, type

```
adb kill-server

adb root

adb shell 

su

busybox rm /system/<you're location>
```

rm will remove the file specified, in this case it's the boot animation file ... Once removed, your device will boot with a stock android logo or a blank screen !

Comment: actually using adb is good but little difficult for beginers.. but you really gave a good idea.. thanks mate

Comment: `adb root` wouldn't work on a production build of a kernel and given that you're already suggesting 'su', it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Look into restoring the stock ROM. This site appears to have it: http://firmwarefile.com/bsnl-penta-ws704dx they recommend using SP Flash Tool so it's Mediatek device, you may just be able to update the 'LOGO' Parition in order to fix it, but if that don't work then completely restore the stock rom.